# Group report by Age

Tags: crystal-reports

Currently my report is grouped by `AR Account`. On top of this grouping I want to group based on date range. (Like 0-30 days old entries, 30-60, and 60 and above.)

How can I add this into my Crystal Report?

Comment: what does AR Account containg and if you group by AR account how does group data gets displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create different formulas for this purpose:

1. `@DateRange` : `DateDiff('d', {?@FromDate}, {?@ToDate})`
2. `@Zero30`
   that contains the following formula: `IF (@DateRange > 0) and (@DateRange <=30 ) then SomeData ELSE 0`
3. `@30-60`
   that contains: `IF (@DateRange > 30) and (@DateRange <=60 ) then SomeData ELSE 0`
4. `60Above` that contains: IF (@DateRange > 30) and (@DateRange <=60 ) then SomeData ELSE 0`

In this way you are eliminating the unneeded data, then list the new formulas in the report.